# Save multiple files in many folders as one file per folder in R

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, export

I want to scan recursively all folders in `getwd()`, pick those matching a pattern, add folder name as a new `subject` column and write a single `.csv` for each folder.

So far I managed to do the following, but it works only for manually switching folders:

```
library(tidyverse)

dir <- "AP4T/"     
APT4 <-
list.files(path = dir, pattern = "*_PULS.log") %>%
map_df(~read_table2(., skip = 5), .id="file") %>%
select(-CHANNEL, -SIGNAL)

write_csv2(APT4, path = "APT4T/resp.csv")
```

While this codes work I'm having a hard time manually changing hundrets of folder and I belive there is a way to automate it, but can't figure out how.

For example:

```
dir<-list.dirs(, full.names = T, recursive = T)
for(i in dir){
  list.files(path = dir, pattern = "*_RESP.log", full.names = T) %>%
    map_df(~read_table2(., skip = 5), .id="file") %>%
    select(-CHANNEL, -SIGNAL) %>%
    write_csv(., path = "resp.csv")
}
```

Will create one gigantic csv file with ALL files matching the pattern - from all directories and without storing any "directory name" specific column, so that I could identify research subjects.

Also - as even a single file is huge, my processing software works better on one file per participant basis. That's why I'd like to store result matching the pattern in separate files with additional columns for
- number of file from that is meeged within one folder - Works by adding `.id="file` to `~read_table2()` call
- name of folder (folder = subject)

I feel i'm close but still missing some points here.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found my way of doing this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# save list of all directories in main/ folder

dir <-list.dirs (path = "main", full.names = T, recursive = T)

#remove 1st item as it points to main directory

dir <- dir[2:73]

# loop over all directories and aggregate files containing "_RESP"

for(i in 1:length(dir))
{
di <- dir[i]

df<-list.files(path = di, pattern = "*_RESP.log", full.names = T) %>%
  map_df(~read_table2(., skip = 5), .id="file")

# Store each merge in separate files with folder as file name

write.csv(df, file = paste0(di,"_RESP",".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```